# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'place'

Tags: python

im new in Python, and never made my own scripts

Code segment:

```
btn = Button=("text=Clicks 0", "background=#555", "foreground=#ccc",
             "padx=20", "pady=8", "font=16", "command:click_button" )
btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c", height=30, wigth=130  )
```

error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
       btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c", height=30, wigth=130  )
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'place'
```

Why does it gives me error, and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have `btn = Button=(...)`. The second equals sign isn't supposed to be there. You just want `btn = Button(...)`.

Comment: after that says:

    NameError: name 'Button' is not defined

Comment: @lol288988 then you must not have imported Tkinter in your script. `Button` is a Tkinter class, so you have to have Tkinter imported in order to use that class. You'd have to do something like `from Tkinter import *`. If you just did `import Tkinter` then you have to refer to it as `Tkinter.Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from tkinter import button
    
btn = Button("text=Clicks 0", "background=#555", "foreground=#ccc",
                     "padx=20", "pady=8", "font=16", "command:click_button" )
btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c", height=30, wigth=130  )
```